# Ant task for grails loading classpath twice

Tags: grails, ant

I'm using the default `macrodef` from `grails integrate-with --ant`.  As part of my ant task, I need to do a `clean`, `war` and some misc. file operations.  The issue I get is that after the `clean` task is run, the `war` task fails to load grails with a `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`.  Changing ant logging to debug gives an error of `...jline_.dll already loaded in another classloader'`.  Below is my ant file.

```
<project xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" name="ant_project" default="normal">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property file="ant/ant-global.properties" />
    <property name="IsCoverageBuild" value="false"/>
    <property name="DisplayCopiedFilesInWar" value="false"/>
    <property name="warFilename" value="PAC.war"/>
    <property name="ivy.install.version" value="2.2.0" />
    <condition property="ivy.home" value="${env.IVY_HOME}">
      <isset property="env.IVY_HOME" />
    </condition>
    <property name="ivy.home" value="${user.home}/.grails/ivy" />
    <property name="ivy.jar.dir" value="${ivy.home}/lib" />
    <property name="ivy.jar.file" value="${ivy.jar.dir}/ivy-${ivy.install.version}.jar" />

    <target name="download-ivy" unless="offline">
        <available file="${ivy.jar.file}" property="ivy.available"/>
        <antcall target="-download-ivy" />
    </target>

    <target name="-download-ivy" unless="ivy.available">
        <mkdir dir="${ivy.jar.dir}"/>
        <!-- download Ivy from web site so that it can be used even without any special installation -->
        <get src="http://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/ivy/${ivy.install.version}/apache-ivy-${ivy.install.version}-bin.zip"
            dest="${ivy.home}/ivy.zip" usetimestamp="true" verbose="true"/>
        <unzip src="${ivy.home}/ivy.zip" dest="${ivy.jar.dir}">
           <patternset>
                <include name="**/*.jar"/>
            </patternset>
            <mapper type="flatten"/>
        </unzip>
    </target>

    <target name="init-ivy" depends="download-ivy" unless="ivy.lib.path">
      <!-- try to load ivy here from ivy home, in case the user has not already dropped
              it into ant's lib dir (note that the latter copy will always take precedence).
              We will not fail as long as local lib dir exists (it may be empty) and
              ivy is in at least one of ant's lib dir or the local lib dir. -->
        <path id="ivy.lib.path">
            <fileset dir="${ivy.jar.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
        </path>
        <taskdef resource="org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml"
                 uri="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" classpathref="ivy.lib.path"/>
    </target>


    <property name="lib.dir" value="${basedir}/lib"/>

    <macrodef name="grails">
        <attribute name="script"/>
        <attribute name="args" default="" />
        <sequential>
            <grailsTask script="@{script}" args="@{args}" classpathref="grails.classpath">
                <compileClasspath refid="compile.classpath"/>
                <testClasspath refid="test.classpath"/>
                <runtimeClasspath refid="app.classpath"/>
            </grailsTask>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <!-- =================================
          target: resolve
         ================================= -->
    <target name="-resolve" description="--> Retrieve dependencies with ivy" depends="init-ivy">
        <ivy:retrieve pattern="${lib.dir}/[conf]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
    </target>

    <target name="-init-grails" depends="-resolve">
        <path id="grails.classpath">
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}/build"/>
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}"/>
        </path>

        <taskdef name="grailsTask"
                 classname="grails.ant.GrailsTask"
                 classpathref="grails.classpath"/>
    </target>

    <target name="deps-report" depends="-resolve" description="--> Generate report of module dependencies.">
        <ivy:report conf="*"/>
    </target>

    <!-- =================================
          target: clean
         ================================= -->
    <target name="clean" description="--> Cleans a Grails application">
        <mkdir dir="${lib.dir}/build"/>
        <mkdir dir="${lib.dir}/compile"/>
        <mkdir dir="${lib.dir}/runtime"/>
        <mkdir dir="${lib.dir}/test"/>
        <delete failonerror="true">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}/build" includes="*/"/>
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}/compile" includes="*/"/>
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}/runtime" includes="*/"/>
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}/test" includes="*/"/>
        </delete>
        <antcall target="--grails-clean"/>
    </target>

    <!-- extra target to avoid errors on Windows because libs on classpath can not be deleted -->
    <target name="--grails-clean" depends="-init-grails">
        <grails script="Clean"/>
    </target>

    <!-- =================================
          target: compile
         ================================= -->
    <target name="compile" depends="-init-grails" description="--> Compiles a Grails application">
        <grails script="Compile"/>
    </target>

    <!-- =================================
          target: war
         ================================= -->
    <target name="war" depends="-init-grails" description="--> Creates a WAR of a Grails application">
        <grails script="War"/>
    </target>

    <!-- =================================
          target: test
         ================================= -->
    <target name="test" depends="-init-grails" description="--> Run a Grails applications unit tests">
        <grails script="TestApp"/>
    </target>

    <!-- =================================
          target: run
         ================================= -->
    <target name="run" depends="-init-grails" description="--> Runs a Grails application using embedded Jetty">
        <grails script="RunApp"/>
    </target>
    <target name="normal" depends="-init-grails,--grails-clean,war">
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up using was to use `<exec>` instead of the provided macrodef.  Here are a couple of examples of what my grails commands look like now.

```
<!--CLEAN-->
<exec executable="cmd">
       <arg value="/c"/>
       <arg path="${env.GRAILS_HOME}/bin/grails.bat"/>
       <arg value="clean"/>
</exec>

    <!--AddProxy-->
<exec executable="cmd">
        <arg value="/c"/>
        <arg path="${env.GRAILS_HOME}/bin/grails.bat"/>
        <arg value="AddProxy"/>
        <arg value="myProxy"/>
        <arg value="--host=myproxyhost"/>
        <arg value="--port=80"/>
</exec>

  <!--SetProxy-->
<exec executable="cmd">
        <arg value="/c"/>
        <arg path="${env.GRAILS_HOME}/bin/grails.bat"/>
        <arg value="SetProxy"/>
        <arg value="myProxy"/>
</exec>
```